# Is the example quiescently consistent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, consistency

The 'Art of Multiprocessor Programming' book by M. Herlihy and N. Shavit defines the following principles of quiescent consistency[Chapter 3, p. 50]:

- Method calls should appear to happen at one-at-a-time, sequential order;
- Method calls separated by a period of quiescence should appear to take effect in their real-time order.

As I understand both these principles, the method calls before and after the quiescence should be executed sequentially, without any overlapping.

As an example the authors provide a primes counter from chapter 1 stating that:

> A quiescently-consistent shared counter would return numbers, not 
>   necessarily in the order of the `getAndIncrement()` requests, but always 
>   without duplicating or omitting a number."

This is java the code of a counter:

```
public class Counter {

    private long value;

    public Counter(long i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public long getAndIncrement() {
        return value++;
    }
}

Counter counter = new Counter(1);

void primePrint() {
    long i = 0;
    long limit = power(10, 10);

    while (i < limit) {
        i = counter.getAndIncrement();
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this example is quiescently consistent? As I see from the code the thread do may overlap and return duplicates. The same is given in the chapter 1 of the book:[p. 5]

> They might simultaneously read 1 from value, set their local temp variables to 1, value to 2, and both return 1.

Comment: The constructor of `Counter` should accept a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: As per the book, it is `int`. This is a widening of `int` into `long`.

Comment: I understand it will compile and run, but it makes more sense to just accept a `long`, or convert the other `long`s to `int`s

Comment: Ok. Adjusted to `long`.

Comment: I think idea there is that given `Counter` serves as an example of code that returns no duplicates, as long as it is not being called concurrently, that's all.

Comment: I think I should have paid attention to the 'would' modal verb.) It is not a quiescently consistent counter.